# Advice required in understanding the logic/maths in encryption program

Tags: python, encryption, ascii

```
userPhrase = input('Enter a single word phrase to be encrypted: ') 
userPhrase = userPhrase.lower() 
key = int(input('Enter a key: ')) 
encryptedPhrase = '' 

for character in userPhrase: 
    x = ord(character) - 97
    x += key
    x = x % 26
    encryptedPhrase += chr(x + 97)

print('Encrypted phrase is ' + encryptedPhrase)
```

I've written a simple encryption program above, mainly following guides online, however all the material I've read through doesn't adequately explain why the ASCII value of the encrypted character is subtracted/reduced by the ASCII value of A(97). As in the line:

```
x = ord(character) - 97
```

Any explanations would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: Check the output of `chr(97)`.

Answer (score 1):

In ASCII, the lower case alphabet `a-z` starts at point `ord('a') == 97`. Therefore, `ord(character) - 97` maps `a-z` to the integer range `0...25`.

Your encryption, which is a Caesar cipher, then shifts that range to the right by the value of `key`, wrapping around due to `x = x % 26`. So for example, if `key` is 5, `0` maps to `5`, `20` maps to `25`, `21` maps to `0`, etc.

Turning this modified alphabet back into ASCII characters, you need to add back the code point for `ord('a')`, hence the `chr(x + 97)`.